# Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine SSL Certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, google-compute-engine, mean-stack

Followed the instructions here to add an ssl cert: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates

but when I access my domain from https://example2.com I get an error that the cert is "Your connection is not secure

The owner of mydomain.com has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website."

When I expand the cert that it shows it says www.example.com rather than www.example2.com.  It's almost like it's using a default.

For what it's worth I'm using the Mean Stack instance. I tried configuring the apache ssl but there was no virtualhost entry in the http.conf file and modifying that file to include didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a painful problem to solve. Turns out it was an issue with Bitnami MEAN. Updating the traditional apache config files wasn't the solution. instead I needed to update the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf file.

Found the answer from this forum: https://community.bitnami.com/t/cannot-start-apache2-when-loading-extra-httpd-ssl-conf-on-wamp-stack/21980/5

specify the path where you have to put your certificate and key are

SSLCertificateFile "installdir/apache2/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "installdir/apache2/conf/server.key"